# Needing help with Vaporwave inspired Illuminated grid (Eevee 2.8)

Tags: mesh

I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTdEtf1YTTI
I got to the part of 4:11 but what I'm getting as a result is not the same as the video. I cannot create an illuminated grid using a simple shade mixer node... It shows up pink and half-filled. I believe there was an update that happened from the date of the video until now. Forgive me since I am fairly new to the program but trying to learn. Help is appreciated! [image: This is what I end up with]

What I'm aiming for is this (underneath)[image: My end goal(screenshot of video)]

Answer (score 1):

Eevee currently seems to have issues with the wireframe node, in cycles it seems to be rendering correctly.

[image]